# Get the value from already routed url in codeigniter

Tags: php, routes, url-routing

I have a routing in my codeigniter route.php that is

```
$route ['business-numbers/(:any)'] = "Home/selectedPlan/$1";
```

after routing my url is mentioned below.

```
business-numbers/buy-uk-numbers/Norwich?1603
```

if the url is this  `business-numbers/buy-uk-numbers/Norwich?1063` i need to get the value 1603 by get method.

Is there any idea to get the value already routed url?